# Background image of selected cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to change cell background image on click on cell in iphone????I have tried following but it is not working....

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50) reuseIdentifier:myid] autorelease];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

In the above piece of code you forget to autorelease; also have you set the delegate of the tableview? Set a breakpoint on the `tableview:didselectRowAtIndexpath` method to check if it is called or not.

BTW your code seems right.

Comment: how about tables with multiple sections? if i use the above code, cells that are rounded (the first and last in every section) will have a rectangle on finger over which doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selectionType of UITableView

using

```
cell.setSelectionStyle = [UITableViewSelectionStyleGray/Blue/None] (only 3 types)
```

some syntex error in above code try with proper syntex

by default it will be blue...

Comment: hi,yakub_moriss

we can also create selection color of any type. Using a view as selected BackgroundView. BTW i know how to chnage selection of UITableViewCell. Thanks for comments

Answer (score 0):

cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mImage.png"]]