# How can i change the background color of a table cell with multiple sections?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with multiple sections and don't know how to change the background color when i touch that row.

I've found this link about table cells but it is addressed to tables with only one section :

[changing cell background on click on cell in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598062/changing-cell-background-on-click-on-cell-in-iphone).

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[ UIView alloc] init];
[cell.selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

if i use the code from this link, cells that are rounded (the first and last in every section) will have a rectangle on finger over which doesn't look good.

How can i make this rectangle curved around the edges for the first and last row in every section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using some quartz core. you can make any view round rect using `view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;`

make sure to import header

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

**EDIT**

Try to create custom cell then and set a UIView for background view property and change color as you wish. That way it will work.

**UPDATE**

Yes you are right. There is tutorial on internet for grouped tableView's let me google it for you. Use this post it has everything you need http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/25/customizing-the-background-border-colors-of-a-uitableview/

here is another stackoverflow post for the same

[How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)

Comment: ok but it makes all my corners round. How can i make only a specific corner round?

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm just going to stick with quartzCore, it isn't that noticeable..